# Get field value from mongoDB and assign to a var gives undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using MeteorJS and trying to get the value of a field from MongoDB and assign to a variable. But when want to print to console, it gives all the time 'undefined'. It works fine in HTML template, but i need to store the value in a var in .js file.

```
var num = ButtonsList.find({_id:'ZcLkjSwNGTpgHkoeq'});
    var n = num.button1;
    console.log("button number is: "+n);
```

The code below works fine by the way, if i want them to output in the browser. It outputs the buttons numbers in html using {{}} namespace. But as I said, i need to store the values in variables.

```
ButtonsList = new Meteor.Collection('list');

Template.theList.helpers({
'buttons': function(){
    //return ButtonsList.find().fetch();
    return ButtonsList.find('ZcLkjSwNGTpgHkoeq');
}
});
```

Comment: write `console.log(num);` and see what you get

Comment: console.log(num); returns an [object Object]

Answer (score 2):

`ButtonsList.find()` returns a cursor.

`ButtonsList.find().fetch()` returns an array of buttons.

`ButtonsList.findOne()` returns will return a single button.

`ButtonsList.findOne().fieldName` will return the field `fieldName` of the button that was found.

The reason it works with the `{{#each}}` template block helper is that `each` blocks know how to iterate over cursors.

Answer (score 1):

Your using Find , doesnt that mean your getting multiple reccords back? Shouldnt you be using FindOne instead? otherwise youll get an array of objects which means youd have to use num[i].button1 to get to the value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it works now! It seems that I wasn't specifying the index of the objects. Now I changed to findOne() and gives the value. Thanks